# How to show / hide Palette window in Netbeans 7.4

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, palette

I use windows 8 and Netbeans  7.4 . Even I create a web application I cannot find palette from the project.

How can I make it visible ?

Comment: Did you do [Window] -> [IDE Tools] -> [Palette]?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the answer, it's placed in:

**Window---> IDE Tools--> Palette**

This can be used to show/hide palette.

Answer (score 2):

Please use 'Reset Windows' in 'Windows' Section to reset the entire page so that you will get all the items like properties, projects, files, services back in place.

Answer (score 1):

[image: window--> ide tools-->palette]

Or use this keyboard shortcut 
Use Ctrl+shift +8

Comment: here everything exist.

Answer (score 1):

For Netbeans 8 use: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>. You can then drag it to any section of the window where you want it to appear.