# Can't find any AWT/Swing components like button, label, etc. in my palette tab in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I can't find the list of components in my palette tab. It only shows choose beans and doesn't show any AWT/Swing components like label, button, etc. Can you help me to get those components?

I have tried resetting the palette. Also I have uninstalled the netbeans and reinstalled it again.

[Here is the screenshot of my palette tab which doesn't show any components.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoUqX.png)

[Here is a screenshot of Palette Manager.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tv4Jz.png)

Comment: Is it a Swing based project or a simple project on which you add a JFrame ?

Comment: Its just a simple project I was practicing.

Comment: Yes I know. I guess if you select Swing type project when you create a project. Your palette will be available.

Comment: I have already tried selecting Swing type project too. But the result is same. The palette components are still unavailable.

Comment: Hope this link will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338953/how-to-show-hide-palette-window-in-netbeans-7-4

Comment: I have already seen this thread and nothing in the answers worked

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue by uninstalling Netbeans(Official Page Installation) by using Snap Install package and afterwards, all the components appeared.